# using selenium for collecting js scripts parsed on the webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way using selenium to collect js scripts that are parsed insside webpage? I know it is possible to do that by listening to  [**scriptparsed** event in chrome debugging protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Debugger/#event-scriptParsed). Is it possible to do the same by using selenium webdriver?

Comment: What would be the purpose? Can you provide an example?

Comment: My main goal is to collect any javascript that is parsed by v8 engine on the webpage.